# How to replace a matching string if n+2 line contains a particular string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

for eg: replace com.icc.id with "abc" if n+2 line (version line contains com.icc.id.version). If it is something else, do not replace. This should be applicable to all pom files present in all sub-directories for a folder "common"

```
<groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
<groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
<artifactId>ifd</artifactId>
<version>${com.icc.id.version}</version>
```

Comment: @user312307 please remember to [accept](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) whichever answer you choose by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for your response, Suppose if the condition is that i+2 line should not contain /com\.icc\.id\.version/ then replace. I tried with !~, it did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the original `xml` example (the tags needed fixing first as `dependencies` wasn't closed) and using `xmlstarlet`

```
xmlstarlet ed -N "x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "//x:dependency[x:version[contains(text(), 'com.icc.version')]]/x:groupId" -v "BANANA" data.xml
```

**Edit**

Wrt the dual constraint that changes are made to `groupId` only where `version` contains `com.icc.version` and `groupId` is not `com.icc.id` then the following should only select and replace those nodes

```
xmlstarlet ed -N "x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "//x:dependency[x:version[contains(text(), 'com.icc.version')]]/x:groupId[not(contains(text(), 'com.icc.id'))]" -v 'BANANA' data.xml
```

or if the entire text of the `groupID` node is `com.icc.id` then

```
xmlstarlet ed -N "x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "//x:dependency[x:version[contains(text(), 'com.icc.version')]]/x:groupId[text() !='com.icc.id']" -v 'BANANA' data.xml
```

The `globstar` loop from @terdon will find the files and the output will go to `stdout` for you to check. To make the changes permanent in the `.pom` files then include the `-L` option in the command.

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -N  etc.....
```

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>solution-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.id.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.banana</groupId>
            <artifactId>application-common</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>application-common</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.banana}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Ouput

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>solution-commons</artifactId>
      <version>${com.icc.id.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>BANANA</groupId>
      <artifactId>application-common</artifactId>
      <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>application-common</artifactId>
      <version>${com.icc.banana}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

One **warning** on this. `xmlstarlet` relies upon knowing the `namespace`, so if the `namespace` is the same in all files then, no problem. If it is different then you will need to interrogate each file and determine the `namespace` and pass it in as a variable.

```
ns=$(grep -Po "(?<=xmlns=\")[^\"]*" data.xml)
```

Comment: Can I use this command in a shell script?

Comment: I tried this command but I also need to have a checkpoint for groupid that if it is abc and version is  xyz then only replace. Current command is replacing if version is xyz even if group-id is not abc

Comment: Thanks bu5hman for this amazing solution, it works like magic

Comment: You are welcome. If you work with `xml` a lot then it is well worth using a proper xml parser like `xmlstarlet` and getting your head around `xpath`. A good free resource for `xpath` is [w3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) if you need.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate

Answer (score 2):

This is more than you need but it sets you up to be able to do a lot more with your records in future:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { numLines = 3 }
{
    lineNr = (NR - 1) % numLines + 1
    rec[lineNr] = $0
}
lineNr == numLines {
    if ( rec[3] ~ /com\.icc\.id\.version/ ) {
        sub(/com\.icc\.id/,"abc",rec[1])
    }
    for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
        print rec[lineNr]
    }
    delete rec
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
(groupId)com.icc.id(/groupId)
(artifactId)abc(/artifactId)
(version)${project.version}(/version)
(groupId)abc(/groupId)
(artifactId)ifd(/artifactId)
(version)${com.icc.id.version}(/version)
```

To do it with all ".pom" files in all sub-directories, assuming "pom files" have such an extension and using GNU awk for `-i inplace`:

```
find . -name '*.pom' -exec awk -i inplace -f tst.awk {} +
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Suppose if the condition is that i+2 line should not contain /com\.icc\.id\.version/ then replace. I tried with !~, it did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're welcome. You already accepted an answer so you should be asking followup questions of the person whose answer you accepted.

Comment: Yes, I have also posted the same question to that user yesterday, but have not got any response so far. And your solution also works for me, hence thought of checking with you.

Comment: what does numlines=3 represent? I just wanted to understand the logic how this works for a sample file and not a pom file which has more than 1000 records.

Comment: The number of lines in each record. Your input is groups of 3 lines at a time so you should consider every such group as a complete record for processing.

Comment: Okay, but we do not have 3 line uniform pattern in the pom file , it can have module dependencies in between, so the grouping can go wrong right?

Comment: It can be whatever it needs to be but all we have to go on is the sample input you provided and creating 3-line records is the right approach for **that input**. If your real input is different from that then you'd need to provide a more truly representative example in your question to get an answer that addresses that real input format.

Comment: I have added more relative pom.xml now for better reference but the fact is that there could be multiple pom files in that directory or its sub-directories and the number of lines could vary.

Comment: Then the number of lines wouldn't be an appropriate way to group lines into records, you'd use some other approach.

Comment: You're turning this into a completely different question - please put it back as it was and then ask a new question if you have one with it's own MCVE including concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Okay, So I have removed the edits from this question and posted a new question here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526269/how-to-replace-a-matching-string-if-n2-line-does-not-contain-a-particular-strin

Answer (score 2):

Store the n and n+1 lines in hold when there's a match on the n-th. Read the n+2 th and examine it for the prescribed content. Upon match, recall the hold and perform the substitution to abc.

```
 $ sed -ne '
     />com\.icc\.id</!bp
     N;h;n
     /\<com\.icc\.id\.version\>/{
         x;s/>com\.icc\.id<\(.*\n\)/>abc<\1/;x
    }
     x;G;:p;p
 ' inp.pom
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is small enough to fit in memory, you can do:

```
$ awk '{lines[NR]=$0}END{for(i in lines){ if(lines[i] ~ /com\.icc\.id/ && lines[i+2] ~ /com\.icc\.id\.version/){gsub("com\\.icc\\.id","abc",lines[i])} print lines[i]}}' file 
(groupId)com.icc.id(/groupId)
(artifactId)abc(/artifactId)
(version)${project.version}(/version)
(groupId)abc(/groupId)
(artifactId)ifd(/artifactId)
(version)${com.icc.id.version}(/version)
```

Or, slightly more readbly:

```
$ awk '{
        lines[NR]=$0
       }
       END{
            for(i in lines){ 
                if(lines[i] ~ /com\.icc\.id/ && 
                   lines[i+2] ~ /com\.icc\.id\.version/){
                        gsub(/com\.icc\.id/,"abc",lines[i])
                } 
            print lines[i]
            }
       }' file 
(groupId)com.icc.id(/groupId)
(artifactId)abc(/artifactId)
(version)${project.version}(/version)
(groupId)abc(/groupId)
(artifactId)ifd(/artifactId)
(version)${com.icc.id.version}(/version)
```

To apply this to all files with the extension `.pom` (I assume that's what you mean by "pom files") in the directory `common` and any subdirectories, you can do this (assuming you are using `bash`, and GNU `gawk`):

```
shopt -s globstar
tmpFile=$(mktemp)
for file in common/**/*.pom; do
    awk '{
    lines[NR]=$0
   }
   END{
        for(i in lines){ 
            if(lines[i] ~ /com\.icc\.id/ && 
               lines[i+2] ~ /com\.icc\.id\.version/){
                    gsub(/com\.icc\.id/,"abc",lines[i])
            } 
        print lines[i]
        }
   }' "$file" > "$tmpFile" && mv "$tmpFile" "$file"
   done
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ed`:

```
printf 'g/com\.icc\.id\.version/-2 s/com\.icc\.id/abc/\n,wq\n' | ed -s file.pom
```