# How to replace a matching string if n+2 line does not contain a particular string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>idp-parent</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>${project.name} - Hello World Web App</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>solution-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.id.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>application-common</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-commons-hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-commons-health</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-commons-rabbitmq</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-commons-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-commons-security</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-commons-system</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-commons-web</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-connector-cache</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-connector-spring-remoting</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-openid-connect</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icc.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-rest-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${com.icc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- The following log4j 1.2 bridge is needed to satisfy libraries that has runtime dependency on log4j 1.2. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

</project>
```

So pom.xml could be something like this..So the requirement is that scan each line and search for com.icc.id , if it is found then replacement should only happen if n+2 line does not contain com.icc.id.version (version line contains com.icc.id.version). If it does not contains - com.icc.id.version, groupid should be replaced to com.uxpsystems.$1 (where $1 is passed as argument to this script) If it contains, skip that block and check the next line if it contains com.icc.id

Comment: It's XML so this shouldn't be about scanning lines but rather about matching elements and paths. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Since we are injecting data(by means of `$1`) into the rhs of a `s///` sed command, we need to quote it properly, so that when it gets plugged into the sed code, no errors should be triggered.

Note: As has been pointed out to you already, the right way to approach this is via an xml tool.

```
$ v1_esc=$(printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed -e 's:[\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/')
$ sed -e '
   /com[.]icc[.]id/!b
   $!N;$!N;/\n.*\n/!q
   /.*\n.*\n.*com[.]icc[.]id[.]version/b
   '"s/com[.]icc[.]id\\(.*\\n.*\\n\\)/com.uxpsystems.${var}\\1/"'
' pom.xml
```

**Explanation:**

- Skip noninteresting lines and print them out as is.
- Grab 3 lines, starting the count from the interesting line.
- While in this process of grabbing 3 lines, you run out of lines, meaning, you reach the eof, then just bail out and print the pattern space as is.
- if we have managed  to reach here, means we have 3 lines in the pattern space for `sed` to look at and the first of those is the interesting line.
- skip processing this block of 3 lines in case the 3rd does not happen to have the prescribed string com.icc.id.version in it, and print it as it is.
- we are here means, the right block of 3 lines has at last been detected and now you should be performing the desired subsitution.

Answer (score 0):

This seems simple enough to do with `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

xmlstarlet ed -N ns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u \
    '//ns:dependency[ns:groupId = "com.icc.id" and not(ns:version = "${com.icc.version}")]/ns:version' \
    -v "com.uxpsystems.$1" file.xml
```

This selects all `version` nodes with text other than `${com.icc.version}` that are child-nodes of `dependency` nodes that also have a `groupID` node with text `com.icc.id`.  The selected `version` nodes are alla updated to have text `com.uxpsystems.$1`, where `$1` is the first argument given to the script.

Answer (score -1):

either parser or load lines into buffer like this:

```
awk '{line=line1;
      line1=line2;
      line2=$0;}
     /com.icc.id.version/ { if (line ~ "com.icc.id")
       { line = ... replace ... }
     }
     {print line}
     END {print line1; print line}'
```

Note: I've not tested, but it should be very close